# Media Query not working on first page load

Tags: media-queries, android-browser

I'm using the following Media Query to target 16x9 aspect ratio tablets, specifically the Samsung Galaxy Tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style-16x9.css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 1280px) and (device-aspect-ratio:16/9)">
```

One the first page load, it doesn't apply the style-16x9.css style sheet.  When I reload the browser, it takes effect.  This always happen at the beginning of every session when I load the page.  Any reason why that would be?

Also, is there a way to specifically NOT target a certain aspect ratio in a media query?  For example, exclude all 16x9 aspect ratios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of android are you using?
It might probably be related to this [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11961).

To answer your second question just use the [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Media_queries#Operator_precedence) keyword.